Swift Execution Graph: Protocol + Generics Impasse
I'm trying to create a generic acyclic execution graph composed of nodes. Each node has 0 or more inputs and outputs. Each input and output is typed for a specific object type (Double, UIImage, String, etc.). I want to only be able to connect inputs and outputs with matching object types in a 1-to-1 relationship (no multiplexing). It all works right up to the point where I tried to create the Connection object which represents the existence of a connection between a specific input and output on different nodes. Here are simplified versions of my types:
import UIKit

protocol NodeOutput {
    associatedtype Entity
    
    var type: Entity.Type { get }
    var value: Entity { get }
}

protocol NodeInput {
    associatedtype Entity
        
    var type: Entity.Type { get }
    func set(value: Entity)
}

protocol Node {
    var inputs: [any NodeInput] { get }
    var outputs: [any NodeOutput] { get }
}

struct GenericConnection<Input: NodeInput, Output: NodeOutput> where Input.Entity == Output.Entity {
    
    public let input: Input
    public let output: Output
    
    /// Create a new connection object.
    public init(input: Input, output: Output) throws {
        self.input = input
        self.output = output
        
        input.set(value: output.value)
    }
    
    public func activate() throws {
        input.set(value: output.value)
    }
}

// Actual Implementations

class SimpleNodeInput<Entity>: NodeInput {
    
    public var type: Entity.Type { Entity.self }
    public private(set) var value: Entity
    
    public init(value: Entity) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    public func set(value: Entity) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class SimpleNodeOutput<Entity>: NodeOutput {
    public var type: Entity.Type { Entity.self }
    public var value: Entity
    
    public init(value: Entity) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class ConstantColorNode: Node {
    let inputs: [any NodeInput] = []
    private(set) var outputs: [any NodeOutput] = []
    
    public private(set) var color: UIColor {
        didSet {
            _colorOutput.value = color
        }
    }
    
    private var _colorOutput: SimpleNodeOutput<UIColor>
    var colorOutput: any NodeOutput { _colorOutput as any NodeOutput }
    
    public init(color: UIColor) {
        self.color = color
        _colorOutput = SimpleNodeOutput(value: color)
        self.outputs = [colorOutput]
    }
    
    func set(color: UIColor) {
        self.color = color
    }
}

class FinalOutputNode<T>: Node {
    private(set) var inputs: [any NodeInput] = []
    let outputs: [any NodeOutput] = []
    
    var finalInput: any NodeInput
    
    init(initialValue: T) {
        
        finalInput = SimpleNodeInput(value: initialValue)
        self.inputs = [finalInput]
    }
}

let colorNode = ConstantColorNode(color: .red)
let outputNode = FinalOutputNode<UIColor>(initialValue: .blue)
let genericConnection = try GenericConnection(input: outputNode.finalInput, output: colorNode.colorOutput)

So... the Connection type has a compiler error that set cannot be used on type any NodeInput. The GenericConnection type does not have a compiler error until you try to instantiate it, then you get the error that any NodeInput does not conform to NodeInput and any NodeOutput does not conform to NodeOutput.
I'm really not sure how I can model this connection between nodes that need to be constrained to having the same generic type. For the record, I have multiple input and output node types that do things like emit a constant value or query a delegate for their type and value. Just not sure how to do this right, or if its even expressible elegantly without making all of the data Any and then doing runtime type checking (which seems super-gross).

Your GenericConnection is heading down the right path. Why did you try to instantiate it with any NodeInput and any NodeOutput? You should instantiate it with concrete input and output types.

The Inputs and Outputs are stored in the node type as [any NodeInput] and [any NodeOutput], so when you access one of them, it has the any NodeInput type. I didn't want to expose the underlying implementation of the input type, but maybe I have to?

I added some concrete types to demonstrate the error.

Is the number of inputs/outputs known at compile time, or are you going to add new inputs and outputs dynamically at runtime?

I think the actual graph will be made of nodes that have concrete inputs and outputs. The Primary AssociatedTypes tip in AnderCover's answer allowed me to "close the gap" between the abstract protocol type and the need to check concrete types in order to establish valid connections in the graph and actually pass data between outputs and inputs.

You could use primary associated types :
protocol NodeOutput<Entity> {
    associatedtype Entity
    
    var type: Entity.Type { get }
    var value: Entity { get }
}

protocol NodeInput<Entity> {
    associatedtype Entity
    
    var type: Entity.Type { get }
    func set(value: Entity)
}

protocol Node<Entity> {
    associatedtype Entity
    var inputs: [any NodeInput<Entity>] { get }
    var outputs: [any NodeOutput<Entity>] { get }
}

struct GenericConnection<T> {
    
    public let input: any NodeInput<T>
    public let output: any NodeOutput<T>
    
        /// Create a new connection object.
    public init(input: any NodeInput<T>, output: any NodeOutput<T>) throws {
        self.input = input
        self.output = output
        
        input.set(value: output.value)
    }
    
    public func activate() throws {
        input.set(value: output.value)
    }
}

    // Actual Implementations

class SimpleNodeInput<Entity>: NodeInput {
    
    public var type: Entity.Type { Entity.self }
    public private(set) var value: Entity
    
    public init(value: Entity) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    public func set(value: Entity) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class SimpleNodeOutput<Entity>: NodeOutput {
    public var type: Entity.Type { Entity.self }
    public var value: Entity
    
    public init(value: Entity) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class ConstantColorNode: Node {
    let inputs: [any NodeInput<UIColor>] = []
    private(set) var outputs: [any NodeOutput<UIColor>] = []
    
    public private(set) var color: UIColor {
        didSet {
            _colorOutput.value = color
        }
    }
    
    private var _colorOutput: SimpleNodeOutput<UIColor>
    var colorOutput: any NodeOutput<UIColor> { _colorOutput as any NodeOutput<UIColor> }
    
    public init(color: UIColor) {
        self.color = color
        _colorOutput = SimpleNodeOutput(value: color)
        self.outputs = [colorOutput]
    }
    
    func set(color: UIColor) {
        self.color = color
    }
}

class FinalOutputNode<T>: Node {
    private(set) var inputs: [any NodeInput<T>] = []
    let outputs: [any NodeOutput<T>] = []
    
    var finalInput: any NodeInput<T>
    
    init(initialValue: T) {
        
        finalInput = SimpleNodeInput(value: initialValue)
        self.inputs = [finalInput]
    }
}

struct ConnectionBundle {
    public let input: any NodeInput
    public let output: any NodeOutput
    
    init(input: any NodeInput, output: any NodeOutput) {
        self.input = input
        self.output = output
    }
}


let colorNode = ConstantColorNode(color: .red)
let outputNode = FinalOutputNode<UIColor>(initialValue: .blue)
let genericConnection = try GenericConnection(input: outputNode.finalInput, output: colorNode.colorOutput)


Woah! I missed that SE. I'm going to investigate this.

The main issue I'm seeing here is the need to associate the Node protocol with a single type, when often there will be multiple types. Consider the case of a ImageBlendNode which takes 2 UIImage and a Float to determine what the mixing percentage of the 2 images is.

Now that I'm thinking about this in the context of Primary Associated Types, the more I think I need to rethink my Node protocol and the use of the inputs and outputs arrays. They're useful for testing if a node can accept an input/output of a specific type T, but fairly useless for setting up the actual connection. Thanks!
